# ¿Cuándo hacer uso de virtual en un modelo?

Tags: asp.net, mvc, entity-framework

En tutoriales de Code First y Entity Framework me he encontrado diferentes ejemplos en los que se muestra el uso de la propiedad `virtual` en diferentes modelos.

Ejemplo:

```
 public class Student    {        
    public int ID { get; set; }  
    public string LastName { get; set; }   
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }       
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

Otro ejemplo:

```
public class Album    {
   public virtual int AlbumId { get; set; }
   public virtual int GenreId { get; set; }
   public virtual int ArtistId { get; set; }
   public virtual string Title { get; set; }
   public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
   public virtual string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
   public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
   public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
}
```

Por lo que mi pregunta es la siguiente, ¿qué uso tiene la propiedad `virtual` y cúando hacer uso de ella?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`virtual` te permite que una propiedad y método pueda ser sobreescrita por una clase que herede de ella.

Los casos en que la he utilizado han sido mas cuando necesito modificar el comportamiento por defecto de la clase como por ejemplo que al momento de obtener el nombre lo convierta en mayúscula ya que la clase principal no lo hace.

```
public class Persona 
{
    public virtual string Nombre { get; set; }
}

public Cliente : Persona 
{
    public override string Nombre {
        get { base.Nombre.ToUpper(); }
        set { base.Nombre = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Al usar virtual estas usando **LazyLoading** y te cargaran la las entidades de relaciones, Mientras tanto sino usas virtual estas usando **Eager Loading** lo cual para que puedas acceder a las propiedades de navegación debes usar el metodo **Include()**

Ejemplo eager loading :

```
// Usuario
public class Usuario
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nombre { get; set; }
    public List<Factura> Facturas { get; set; } // sin virtual
}

// Factura
public class Factura
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public UsuarioId{ get; set; }
    public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

Tendrias que usar Include() cuando quieras alguna propiedad de navegación.

```
db.Usuario.Include(f => f.Facturas).ToList();

// Tambien lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera
db.Usuarios.Include("Facturas").ToList();
```